# Using Parcelable to pass highly nested classes between Activities

Tags: android, parcelable

Suppose I want to store a custom object of type `MyObject` in an `Intent`. The way to do this is to make `MyObject` implement `Parcelable`. If one of the fields of `MyObject` is also a custom object of type `Widget` the obvious thing to do is to make `Widget` implement `Parcelable` too.

The trouble is that there is a huge amount of boilerplate involved when implementing `Parcelable`. You can get around this by not making `Widget` implement `Parcelable` but instead just giving it a constructor taking a `Parcel` and a method `writeToParcel` as follows:

```
public final class Widget {

    private final int a;
    private final String b;

    Widget(Parcel in) {
        a = in.readInt();
        b = in.readString();
    }

    void writeToParcel(Parcel out) {
        out.writeInt(a);
        out.writeString(b);
    }
}
```

You can then have a `Widget` field in a `Parcelable` object as follows:

```
public class MyObject implements Parcelable {

    private final int x;
    private final Widget w;

    MyObject(int x, Widget w) {
        this.x = x;
        this.w = w;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(x);
        w.writeToParcel(out);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyObject(in.readInt(), new Widget(in));
        }
        @Override
        public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObject[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Is this an acceptable approach? Is it considered unidiomatic android to have many custom classes in a project that can be written to and read from `Parcel`s without them actually implementing `Parcelable`? Or does the fact that I am using a `Parcelable` to pass complex objects with many fields of custom types (which in turn have many fields of custom type etc etc), indicate that I shouldn't be using `Parcelable` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would (and did) go with Parceler: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler

> Parceler is a code generation library that generates the Android
>   Parcelable boilerplate source code. No longer do you have to implement
>   the Parcelable interface, the writeToParcel() or createFromParcel() or
>   the public static final CREATOR. You simply annotate a POJO with
>   @Parcel and Parceler does the rest.

It's really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use `Parcelable` when dealing with passing custom Objects through intents in Android. There isn't an "easy" work around. Since you are dealing with just one extra level of a custom Object (Widget), I would recommend you make `Widget` `Parcelable` also. You can also check out this link to see why it is the better approach than using default Serialization. https://coderwall.com/p/vfbing/passing-objects-between-activities-in-android

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just an example. I think my objects are 4-5 levels deep in reality.

Comment: An Unorthodox way to do it is if you have a class with static fields that you can update when you are going between activities. 
For example **Activity A** will update the `MyObject` field in the static class  before starting intent for **Activity B** and then in the **Activity B** it will read that `MyObject` field from the static class. That way you don't even need to think about Parcelables at all

Comment: @PaulBoddington look above

Comment: I can't tell you how strong the temptation to just do that is. I know that's very unwise though.

Answer (score 0):

If your classes are beans, the best solution is the accepted one. If not, I have found that you can (slightly) reduce the pain of implementing `Parcelable` by creating abstract classes `ParcelablePlus` and `CreatorPlus` like this.

`ParcelablePlus`:

```
abstract class ParcelablePlus implements Parcelable {

    @Override
    public final int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`CreatorPlus`:

```
abstract class CreatorPlus<T extends Parcelable> implements Parcelable.Creator<T> {

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    CreatorPlus(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final T[] newArray(int size) {
        // Safe as long as T is not a generic type.
        return (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
    }
}
```

Then the `Widget` class becomes:

```
public final class Widget extends ParcelablePlus {

    private final int a;
    private final String b;

    Widget(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(a);
        out.writeString(b);
    }

    public static final Creator<Widget> CREATOR = new CreatorPlus<Widget>(Widget.class) {
        @Override
        public Widget createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Widget(in.readInt(), in.readString());
        }
    };
}
```